# `pd.read_csv` выдаёт ошибку: "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 72, saw 8"

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, dataframe, csv

В общем читаю книгу 'Python для сложных задач наука о данных и машинное обучение' и там пример кода :

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data/president_heights.csv')
heights = np.array(data['height(cm)'])
print(heights)
```

У меня этот код не отрабатывает, пытался по разному запустить этот код (вложил в папку anaconda3 это файл) но не вышло.

вот как я сделал (в редакторе):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('E:\\my_folder\\Python\\president_heights.csv')
heights = np.array(data['height(cm)'])
print(heights)
```

либо в терминале:

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Anaconda3\\president_heights.csv')
```

Вот код ошибки , он одинаков как из редактора так и из терминала:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-21-14c66386591b>", line 1, in <module>
    data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Anaconda3\\president_heights.csv')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 446, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1036, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1848, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)

  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 876, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read

  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 891, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory

  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 945, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows

  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 932, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows

  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2112, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 72, saw 8
```

Вот строки c 70 по 74  (71, 73 пустая) из файла president_heights.csv :

```
   <meta name="js-proxy-site-detection-payload" content="YTdhMjllODE5Njc5NjBkYzAxMGUwOTJlYWFhYmQ5YjgzZTlmZTA4OTRlNGJjZGQ4NjMzNTBlM2M0Y2FkZTA0ZHx7InJlbW90ZV9hZGRyZXNzIjoiMTA5LjI1Mi43My4xMCIsInJlcXVlc3RfaWQiOiIwRTY4OjYxNjU6NTVDQkY5OkEyNTA0OTo1Qjc4M0E4RiIsInRpbWVzdGFtcCI6MTUzNDYwNTk3NSwiaG9zdCI6ImdpdGh1Yi5jb20ifQ==">

    <meta name="enabled-features" content="DASHBOARD_V2_LAYOUT_OPT_IN,EXPLORE_DISCOVER_REPOSITORIES,UNIVERSE_BANNER,FREE_TRIALS,MARKETPLACE_INSIGHTS,MARKETPLACE_PLAN_RESTRICTION_EDITOR,MARKETPLACE_SEARCH,MARKETPLACE_INSIGHTS_CONVERSION_PERCENTAGES">


<meta name="enabled-features" content="DASHBOARD_V2_LAYOUT_OPT_IN,EXPLORE_DISCOVER_REPOSITORIES,UNIVERSE_BANNER,FREE_TRIALS,MARKETPLACE_INSIGHTS,MARKETPLACE_PLAN_RESTRICTION_EDITOR,MARKETPLACE_SEARCH,MARKETPLACE_INSIGHTS_CONVERSION_PERCENTAGES">       

  <meta name="html-safe-nonce" content="24cc27afd7691f29ad302e95fae059d2020b557d">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так ??

Comment: Замените скриншоты текстом ошибки.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev сделал.

Comment: Несколько первых строчек csv-файла можете добавить в вопрос?

Comment: @MaxU я думаю это возможно из за того что у меня анаконда установлена без прописи в  PATH

Comment: @timob256, вы можете привести в вопросе строки из вашего CSV с 70 по 73?

Comment: @MaxU так я весь код и привёл

Comment: @timob256, я спрашивал о CSV файле, а не о скрипте

Comment: @MaxU добавил :3

Comment: Вы пытаетесь парсить HTML/XML как CSV??? Как вы получили данный CSV файл?

Comment: @MaxU да я сейчас понимаю полную глупость сего файла, но я его сказал с официального гит хаба (к книге) странно что он такая помойка оказался

Comment: Может вы его не правильно скачали? Есть адрес ?

Comment: @MaxU [вот ссылка](https://github.com/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/tree/master/notebooks/data) _от сюда скачал_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 72, saw 8
```

говорит о том, что парсер ожидает 1 столбец, а в строке 72 он увидел 8 столбцов.

В вашем случае ошибка вызвана тем, что вы неправильно скачали CSV с GitHub. Вот правильный адрес для скачивания: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/master/notebooks/data/president_heights.csv

В первых строках HTML файла отсутствовал символ запятой (разделитель CSV по-умолчанию), поэтому `pd.read_csv()` посчитал, что данный CSV состоит из единственного столбца.

`pd.read_csv()` позволяет читать данные напрямую по ссылке:

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/master/notebooks/data/president_heights.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

результат:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
    order                    name  height(cm)
0       1       George Washington         189
1       2              John Adams         170
2       3        Thomas Jefferson         189
3       4           James Madison         163
4       5            James Monroe         183
5       6       John Quincy Adams         171
6       7          Andrew Jackson         185
7       8        Martin Van Buren         168
8       9  William Henry Harrison         173
9      10              John Tyler         183
..    ...                     ...         ...
32     35         John F. Kennedy         183
33     36       Lyndon B. Johnson         193
34     37           Richard Nixon         182
35     38             Gerald Ford         183
36     39            Jimmy Carter         177
37     40           Ronald Reagan         185
38     41       George H. W. Bush         188
39     42            Bill Clinton         188
40     43          George W. Bush         182
41     44            Barack Obama         185

[42 rows x 3 columns]
```

---

Также данная ошибка часто возникает из-за "поломаных" CSV файлов.

Пример:

```
ID,Text
1,Нормальная строка.
2,ОШИБКА: незаэкранированные запятые: 1,2,3
```

---

```
pd.read_csv(filename)
...
skipped
...
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 4
```

Если исправить CSV, т.е. заэкранировать запятые, не являющиеся разделителями, то все работает правильно:

```
ID,Text
1,"Нормальная строка."
2,"ОШИБКА: незаэкранированные запятые: 1,2,3"
```

результат:

```
   ID                                       Text
0   1                         Нормальная строка.
1   2  ОШИБКА: незаэкранированные запятые: 1,2,3
```